# Do I have to implement a ViewModel when using multiple Models in one View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I want the user to fill in 2 forms on the View. Each form should "represents" a Model. So the View should use 2 Models.

Do I need to implement a ViewModel or can I implement a View with 2 Models?

I already tried with `Tuple<Item1, Item2>` and failed

Comment: Close voted --> off-topic ???

Comment: Not sure why people downvote without leaving the reason.

Comment: IMO, your ViewModel should be a union of both (business) models. Not sure if you can implement a View with 2 models.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14497187/125740

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100% you should create a viewmodel that comprises of the two models you need.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ModelA ModelA { get; set; }
    public ModelB ModelB { get; set; }
}
```

You should keep the association of one view -> one viewmodel class. I keep to this in my MVC apps, and it helps me keep the views simpler.

I would never try to mix two viewmodels in one view; that's making things tricker for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you should make a new viewmodel, which consists of the union of other 2 models.
Also consider the mechanism of MVC *(i,e, why models use, in what way models help, and why do we make them strongly type with views).* This is **why**, models are for. It's also going to support you in a smooth way, while posting your form values to some action, decorated as *[Httppost]*, because it is going to be difficult in case where you do not have a model, or have 2 different models. make something like:

```
public class UserRegModel
{
  public User UserModel{ get; set; }
  public Contact ConModel { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what a `ViewModel` is for.

A `Model` will generally represent a real world object, for example a `Customer` or an `Order`.

A `ViewModel` will be all of the information you need to display your view. That could (as in your case) be a combination of other models, some meta data or anything else.

So even if you *could* pass two models to your view (you can't, easily) then you shouldn't, a `ViewModel` is the correct thing to use.